# Get the two closest points from a list of points

Tags: python, for-loop, closest-points

I am given a list of integers/floats and I need to find the two numbers closest together. How would I do that using only nested for loops?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: Are these points one or two dimensional?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For each element, you have to compare the distance of it to each of the other elements with your previous "closest" value - any time this comparison yields  smaller values, you remember that pair as the "two closest" ones.

So, it is straightforward:

```
def find_two_closest(numbers):
    # most distant points:
    delta = max(numbers), min(numbers)
    for i, element in enumerate(numbers):
        for j, sec_element in enumerate(numbers):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if abs(sec_element - element) < abs(delta[0] - delta[1]):
                delta = sec_element, element
    return delta
```

Comment: Not that this is a "dumb" O(N²) thing - so, for about 1000 numbers, you make 1000000 comaprisons, which might be ok for your purpose. If you need smarter ways, an algorithm that would break your list in clusters grouped by mutual proximity, and only compare elements inside each cluster between themselves would be much better. (since any number outside the cluster would already be at a distance greater than some intermediary value you'd have figured out on the first passes)

Comment: @CodingLambdas Well in this case the condition may be simplified to `not(sec_element == element) and abs(sec_element - element) < abs(delta[0] - delta[1])` where the subsequent conditions are ignored if the preceding ones fail. So I'm not sure I'd use it here, but I guess it's more about one's coding style than anything else. There are of course places where `continue` would be invaluable.

Comment: Actually, here I'd use a call to `min` passing it a generator expression with the nested `for` - so, yes, thios is expanded code for readability.

Comment: i also noticed that if a list contains two numbers that are identical, it does not print those two numbers out (i.e. if the list is [3,3,4], it prints out (3, 4) and not (3, 3) like it is supposed to.

Comment: i changed the continue statement to diff = sec_element, element, but it now returns [4,4] even if there is not second 4 in the list

Comment: that condition is there so that it does not compare one element with itself. If you break it, the minimum distance will always be "zero".

Comment: ok, but if i do have a list of [3,3,4], then the output is supposed to be [3,3] since that is the min distance, not 1. how do i fix this issue then

Comment: Compare the numbers by index, to check if they are the same, instead of by value - that is done using "enumerate" and an auxiliar variable in each of the `for` loops. I will update the answer to show that.

Comment: @jsbueno in 1 dimension you don't need to cluster anything, you just need to sort the original list and iterate over the points in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Checking each two points is not necessary and it's slow O(n^2).

I suggest to:
1) Sort the input.
2) Compare each two following values and choose smallest.
Timing will be much better O(n*log n) assuming that you use efficient sorting algorithm.

Code example:

```
input = [0, 65, 10, 100, 1231] #whatever you put here; it might be tuple, list, set, range, etc.

def find_closest(input):
    sorted_input = sorted(input)
    best = (sorted_input[-2], sorted_input[-1], sorted_input[-1] - sorted_input[-2])
    for i, val in enumerate(sorted_input[:-1]):
        d = sorted_input[i+1]-val
        if d < best[2]:
            best = (val, sorted_input[i+1], d) 
return best
```

Function returns both values and distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

If the points are one dimensional (as in your input is just a list of numbers like `[1, 4, 6, 2]`), then you can easily do it in O(n log n) time by sorting them and finding the ones with the smallest difference:

```
def smallest_difference(points):
    sorted_points = sorted(points)
    return min(abs(prev - cur) for cur, prev in zip(sorted_points, sorted_points[1:]))
```

If you want to get the closest points instead of the distance between the closest points, use the `key=` parameter of the `min` function:

```
import operator

def smallest_difference(points):
    sorted_points = sorted(points)
    return min(zip(sorted_points, sorted_points[1:]), key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - x[0]))
```

If the points are two dimensional (as in your input is a list of 2 element tuples like `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 2)]`) then the Wikipedia article for this problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem describes how to extend this to two dimensions.